# Why have a different salt for every password?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, cryptography

Adding a long salt prevents an attacker to use a rainbow table attack. I add, for example, `fve4qrwgfAGVWRVfedSGFGBVSEASionvwegsf32` to all the passwords before hashing, he's definitely not going to have a rainbow table for these words.

So, why use a different salt for every password? The only reason I see is that an attacker could create a rainbow table once with the default salt, and use that rainbow table then. Is that it?

Comment: Because even if you figure out the salt, it will only work with one password.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The salt is already as public as the hash, so there is nothing to figure out.

Comment: Salts prevent multi-target attacks, i.e. validating one password guess against many hashes. Rainbow tables are just one form of multi-target attack, typically not the best even without salt.